# Is there a (good) mail-client or website to design and send emails?

Tags: software-recommendation, e-mail

I want to give the e-mails I send professionally a good look. I am using OS X. Is there a mail-client or website that lets me design the e-mails I am sending to customers? In my case typography, spacing (and maybe usage of images) would be enough.

Comment: I've always felt for direct communication, only **plain text** email should be used. Email is meant to convey information, not  look pretty.

Comment: @Scott Any design of your product affects your customers and clients. This accounts for products in the real world (see Apple), websites—and e-mails. A plain-text e-mail is a design *too*, if you want it or not. Apart from that, I am aiming for specific thought-through typography and spacing, not overloaded graphics if that is what you're opinionated against.

Comment: Context is everything. What kind of emails are we talking about? For business correspondence, I'm with Scott. Plain text. For marketing email lists, you can use something like MailChimp.

Comment: @Dom I, as a user, mostly despise html email. Email is most usable as plain text. I want to read it on my desktop, my phone, my tablet. I want the text to be at the size *I* set--not the designer's preference. I want it to be extremely easy to cut and paste and reply to. HTML rarely makes an email more usable. And if we're talking business correspondence, the content is what's most important. My 2 cents.

Comment: Maybe another way to spin it: Email is designed well when it's left simple. Less is more when it comes to email, IMHO.

Comment: I'm with @Da01 entirely here. Email for communication should be trouble free and functional, thus plain text. Marketing is a different matter entirely. My email client will not even render HTML email unless I ask it to specifically. HTML email is pointless for actually communicating important information.

Comment: @Dom the reason email is often 'switched' back to plain-text on reply is that it's simply easier to reply that way. Another argument for plain text. :) To be clear, I'm mainly advocating for plain text when the communication is person-to-person.

Comment: Mass marketing to clients, such as LinkIn, is *not* the same as direct client communication. You really can't compare a company communicating to it's faceless customers to a designer communicating with their personal clients. And for the record, Linked in emails to me are just a mess of HTML and are trashed almost immediately. If they are serious, there would be a plain text version rendered for the email.

Comment: The real problem with HTML emails is that you cannot ever guarantee what they'll look like to the recipient (platform, device, mail client, browser). You can get reasonably close, but it will never match, and some people will strip out all your design altogether. Plus images just make the mail larger and slower. Make it look like a nice business letter, but in straightforward text. Maybe Times vs. "random font" and subtle color *at best.*

Comment: First of all, as I said, I am aiming for nicer typography, not images and blinking text all over the place. Second of all, are you really using plain text? Because when you open your e-mail-client or web-interface you write HTML mails by default, even if you don't *use* formatting, the font and font size etc is chosen by your mail-client and every mail-client does it differently. By default no mail-client uses plain text. Please check if you are really not using HTML.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum That is a big topic in the software development world, that's why there are (responsive) HTML email boilerplates and services like MailChimp and campaignmonitor try to address this issue too.